# column chart is taking 10 times the value for second data in the series

Tags: javascript

var suspendPassVal= document.getElementById("suspendpass20").value;

```
console.log("suspendPassVal"+suspendPassVal);
```

var suspendFailVal= document.getElementById("suspendfail20").value;

console.log("suspenFailsVal"+suspendFailVal);

var mdnInvCheckPassVal= document.getElementById("mdnInvCheckpass20").value;

console.log("mdnPassVal"+mdnInvCheckPassVal);

var mdnInvCheckFailVal= document.getElementById("mdnInvCheckfail20").value;

console.log("mdnFailsVal"+mdnInvCheckFailVal);

var tniFuncsPassVal= document.getElementById("tniFuncspass20").value;

console.log("tniPassVal"+tniFuncsPassVal);

var tniFuncsFailVal= document.getElementById("tniFuncsfail20").value;

console.log("tniFailsVal"+tniFuncsFailVal);

var reconnectPassVal= document.getElementById("reconnectpass20").value;

console.log("reconnectPassVal"+reconnectPassVal);

var reconnectFailVal= document.getElementById("reconnectfail20").value;

console.log("reconnectFailsVal"+reconnectFailVal);

var reactivatePassVal= document.getElementById("reactivatepass20").value;

console.log("reactivatePassVal"+reactivatePassVal);

var reactivateFailVal= document.getElementById("reactivatefail20").value;
   console.log("reactivateFailsVal"+reactivateFailVal);

```
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                position: "bottom",
                text: "Module Based statistics"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "bar",
                stack: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Failed",
                data: [suspendFailVal, mdnInvCheckFailVal, tniFuncsFailVal, reconnectFailVal, reactivateFailVal],
                color: "#ff0000"
            },{
                name: "Passed",
                data: [ suspendPassVal,  mdnInvCheckPassVal, tniFuncsPassVal,  reconnectPassVal, reactivatePassVal],
                color: "#00ff00"
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                 max: 10,
                majorUnit:1,
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                minorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: ['Suspend', 'MDN', 'TNI', 'reconnect', 'reactive'],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(createChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
</script>
```

when i hard code the values `[1,2,4,3,5]` and `[2,3,5,6,6]` it is giving me the proper aligned graph. but if i go with above given variables, second series of data is taking 10 times.

can anybody help me wi this issue.

Comment: How do you calculate those? If hardcoding the values gives you what you expect, but using variables is wrong, then perhaps it is the values of those variables.

Comment: agreed with @krillgar. are you sure your variable values are the same? print them out.

Comment: no, i got the values in the variables[1,2,3,4,5] but it is taking [10,20,30,40,50] in the graph. as am getting the values from server side i checked in the alert

Comment: yes am sure, i printed them

Comment: we're gonna need to see more code

Comment: added the complete code